# How to place different weights on different slices in one volume in 3D semantic segmantation of keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm now working on a 3D multi-class semantic segmentation task with Keras.

I know there is a way like weighted cross entropy that can increase the weight of each class. But I'm wondering is there a possible way to add different weights on different slices in one input volume?

For example, let X denote the number of slices, and W is the weight. I'm now trying to set a dynamic weighted cross entropy as W=sqrt(X). But I don't how exactly to realize it in Keras.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean W=sqrt(X) ? don't you want to set a different weight for each slice ? in this case i'd expect a formula in the form `W_i = f(i)`

Comment: Hi,thanks for help, but I don't understand W_i = f(i) clearly,  could you explain your code more in detail?

Comment: I understood that you want the weight of each slice to depend on the slice index, is that correct ? so the weight of slice i (denoted as `W_i`) is a function of i `f(i)` (i the index of the slice)

Comment: Yes, That's right, but I have difficult in the implement of it in Keras. I don't know whether it is possible in Keras.